# jquery animate() does not work in prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, prototype

Why does this jquery line not work if I call the prototype?

```
$("#demo").animate({left: '250px'});
```

See in context below:

This line:

```
$("#demo").css("background-color","red");
```

works as I expect it to.

Complete Code:

```
<body>
  <style>
    #demo{width: 400px;}
    button {padding: 10px; background-color: #3f8aca; color: #fff; 
        border-radius: 3px; margin:100px 0 0 100px; border: none;}
  </style>
  <div id="demo"></div>
  <button onclick="porsche.drive();">My Porsche drives.</button>

  <script>
    function Car(){}

    var porsche = new Car(), 
        lancia = new Car();

    Car.fn = Car.prototype;

    Car.fn.drive = function drive(){
      console.log("Yeahh, I´m driving there!");
      document
        .getElementById("demo")
        .innerHTML = "Yeahh, I´m driving there!";
      $("#demo").css("background-color","red");

      // The line below does not work.
      $("#demo").animate({left: '250px'});
    }

    Car.fn.stops = function stops(){
      console.log("Oh, I´ve to stop here!");
    }

    lancia.stops();
  </script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Thanks for your advice,
Markus

Comment: Your variable declarations are in the Car function and there for are only available in the scope of the function, `var porsche = new Car(), lancia = new Car();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add `position: relative;` like this :

```
#demo {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
  }
```

and add `duration` option :

```
$("#demo").animate({left: '250px'},{duration:2000});
```

Final code :

```html
<body>
  <style>
    #demo{
        width: 400px;
        position: relative;
      }
    button {padding: 10px; background-color: #3f8aca; color: #fff; border-radius: 3px; margin:100px 0 0 100px; border: none;}
  </style>
  <div id="demo"></div>
  <button onclick="porsche.drive();">My Porsche drives.</button>

<script>
  function Car(){}
    var porsche = new Car(), lancia = new Car();
    Car.fn = Car.prototype;

    Car.fn.drive = function drive(){
    console.log("Yeahh, I´m driving there!");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Yeahh, I´m driving there!";
    $("#demo").css("background-color","red");
    /* the function below dont works */
    $("#demo").animate({left: '250px'},{duration:2000});

  }
  Car.fn.stops = function stops(){
    console.log("Oh, I´ve to stop here!");
  }
lancia.stops();
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Well, thanks. This solution works well. Setting "position: relative" and all work well. Setting "duration:2000" is not necessary, but the animation looks better with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body>
  <style>
    #demo{
        width: 400px;
        position: relative;
      }
    button {padding: 10px; background-color: #3f8aca; color: #fff; border-radius: 3px; margin:100px 0 0 100px; border: none;}
  </style>
  <div id="demo"></div>
  <button onclick="porsche.drive();">My Porsche drives.</button>

<script>
  function Car(){}
    var porsche = new Car(), lancia = new Car();
    Car.fn = Car.prototype;

    Car.fn.drive = function drive(){
    console.log("Yeahh, I´m driving there!");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Yeahh, I´m driving there!";
    $("#demo").css("background-color","red");
    /* the function below dont works */
    $("#demo").animate({left: '250px'},{duration:2000});

  }
  Car.fn.stops = function stops(){
    console.log("Oh, I´ve to stop here!");
  }
lancia.stops();
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    
    </script>
</body>
```